# how to show json array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

```
<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("bmwcci").innerHTML = myObj.accounts;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "listbmwcci.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

it just showing
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

how to get "login": "admin@bmwcci.org" in "accounts":

```
 "accounts": [{"uid": 1130000025409057, "iname": "", "sex": null, "ready": "no", "hintq": "", "aliases": [], "enabled": "yes", "maillist": "no", "fname": "", "birth_date": null, "login": "admin@bmwcci.org", "fio": ""},
```

Comment: Why are you parsing it using `JSON.parse(this.responseText)`, if you want to show it?

Comment: You can try `JSON.stringify(myObj.accounts)` to start with. But it would be better to make something like: `myObj.accounts.map((e)=>{ return 'login: '+e.login}).join('<br>')`

Comment: Just write document.getElementById(&quot;bmwcci&quot;).innerHTML = this.responseText
If you would like to use as json you should use JSON.parse then you can access with json notation

Comment: Thanks @Bellian , you save my day 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access like this,`result.accounts[0].login`

**DEMO**

```js
var result = {"accounts": [{"uid": 1130000025409057, "iname": "", "sex": null, "ready": "no", "hintq": "", "aliases": [], "enabled": "yes", "maillist": "no", "fname": "", "birth_date": null, "login": "admin@bmwcci.org", "fio": ""}]};

console.log(result.accounts[0].login);
```